# jQuery form submit event not working at all

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms, form-submit

The following is my code. What I want is for the whenever the form is submitted to run the 3 jQuery lines that move around some positioning and visibility. Right now, whenever I submit the form, nothing happens. Where am I going wrong at?

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
   <html>
<head>
    <title>Webther - What's it like out?</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/desktop.css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    function showResult(str)
    {
    if (str.length==0)
      { 
      document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML="";
      document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="0px";
      return;
      }
    if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
      {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
      xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      }
    else
      {// code for IE6, IE5
      xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
    xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
      {
      if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
        {
        var response=xmlhttp.responseText;
    if (response.length!=0)
      { 
        document.getElementById("livesearch").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        document.getElementById("livesearch").style.border="1px solid #A5ACB2";
      }
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","livesearch.php?q="+str,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }

    function ChangeVal()
    {
    document.getElementById("searchbox").value="";
    }
    </script>
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="pagecontainer">
        <div id="indexlogocontainer">
            <img id="indexlogo" src="images/fulllogo.png" />
        </div>
        <div id="indexsearchcontainer">

                <div id="searchsurround"><form id="searchform"><input type="text" autocomplete="off" id="searchbox" name="q" size="50" value="Enter a city or zipcode here!" onkeyup="showResult(this.value)" onclick="ChangeVal()"/>
                &nbsp;&nbsp;<input type="image"  alt="Go!"   src="images/goicon.jpg" id="searchsubmit" /></form></div>
    <script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(function() {
    $("#indexlogocontainer").animate({ marginTop: '-40px' }, 1000);
    $("#mylocations").fadeOut("slow");
    $("#forecast").fadeIn("slow");
    return false;
  });​
    </script>
                <div id="livesearch"></div>

        </div>
        <div id="mylocations">
            <h1>My Locations</h1>
            <ul>
                <li>BLAH</li>
                <li>Blah!</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id="forecast" style="display: none;">
            PAGE INFO
        </div>
    </div>

</body>
    </html>
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("form").submit(function() {
     $("#indexlogocontainer").animate({ marginTop: '-40px' }, 1000);
     $("#mylocations").fadeOut("slow");
     $("#forecast").fadeIn("slow");
     return false;
  });​

});
```

Basically you have to write the function in document's ready function (preferably in the head section) not below the form tag.

**A few more suggestion about your code**

You are using jQuery's latest version from google code. In future the version may change and few things may get deprecated hence may stop few functionality of your web page. So always use specific version like

`<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js">`

**AND**

Learn and use jQuery's ajax function. That will be short and flexible. refer http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @MatthewRust, if it resolved your problem please accept the answer

Answer (score 0):

You need to add input of type submit or write a call to submit the form

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong there is no submit button and action for a form to submit once you check it using the alert box in the following code .Since form is not submitting the following code is not executing.I added the alert box in comments

```
$("form").submit(function() {
//alert("form is submitted");
$("#indexlogocontainer").animate({ marginTop: '-40px' }, 1000);
$("#mylocations").fadeOut("slow");
$("#forecast").fadeIn("slow");
return false;
});​
```

Answer (score -1):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$("form").submit(function() {
$("#indexlogocontainer").animate({ marginTop: '-40px' }, 1000);
$("#mylocations").fadeOut("slow");
$("#forecast").fadeIn("slow");
return false;
});?
</script>
```

when i try to run the code , i have faced js issue because of unecessary question mark.Please remove the ? after the script... its running fine